# JSON data from client side to Object on server

Tags: json, servlets, gson

Apologies for the confusing title. The question is:
I know how to use gson to convert an Object on the server side into json and send it to client side. I also know how to send json from client to server. On the server side I use request.getParameter("xyz") to get the data I need. However, is there a way that I can directly map the client side data to a Class or Object on the server side.

If for instance there are 100 parameters in the client side data then it would take ages to write all those getParameter statements. Any shortcut for mapping that to an object?

Comment: What server side technologies are you using? Most can handle this automatically.

Comment: I am working on a Java servlet. The way I currently get the data in doGet or doPost is by using request.getParameter()

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have seen that tutorial. The problem for me is that in a servlet I am getting the data in HttpServletRequest not from a file. I dont know how to pass the 'request' to gson.fromJson()

Comment: So just get your JSON string from the request and use `gson.fromJson(string, Whatever.class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use something like this, http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, to convert your JSON into a POJO class, you can use GSON to convert the client request string (postdata?) into an instance of that class.

```
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
       Person p = gson.fromJson(reader, Person.class);
```